# Find same string within two different cells, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to find a string value in two different cells, but to no avail. Perhaps something to do with the search direction. The code finds the string in the first cell, but never in the second cell(the cells are not adjacent)??

Please see extract of code:

```
Dim aCell As Range, bCell, where1, where2
    lastarr = Worksheets("Locations").Range("C50").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If lastarr < 1 Then GoTo end4
    Dim whatar()
    ReDim Preserve whatar(lastarr)
    where1 = .Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 4).Address _
             (RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    where2 = .Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 9).Address _
             (RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    For i = 1 To lastarr
        whatar(i) = Trim(Worksheets("Locations").Cells(i + 1, 3))
        Set aCell = .Range(where1).Find(What:=whatar(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        Set bCell = .Range(where2).Find(What:=whatar(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        rr = Application.Caller.Row
        If Not bCell Is Nothing Then Stop
        'If rr = 439 And i = 3 Then Stop
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Or Not bCell Is Nothing Then  
            gekry = True   '======= trigger!! =========
            'Stop
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: what are those `.Cells` and `.Range` referring to?

Comment: At a glance, this seems pretty clumsy. What are you **really** trying to acheive?

Comment: .Cells are referring to a Worksheets object earlier in the code. I'm adding two dates to a dynamic array, and then test a date against the dates in the array.

Comment: but populating the array is easy, but the problem is in the way I use the find methods?

Comment: "Cells are referring to a Worksheets object earlier in the code" - what worksheet?  Your Find() calls are only looking at single cells, so they seem unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your code and logic but didn't quite make it to the end.  If you are looking for multiple instances of a given string, you can adopt the boilerplate code I usually use for such situations:

```
Dim strFirstFind As String
Dim cll As Range, rng As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:X100")
    Set cll = .Find("X", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cll Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = cll
        strFirstFind = cll.Address
        Do
            Set rng = Union(rng, cll)
            .Range(cll.Address).Activate
            Set cll = .FindNext(cll)

        Loop While Not cll Is Nothing And cll.Address <> strFirstFind
    End If

    Debug.Print rng.Address

End With
```